# using a form to fill an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I'm trying to make a form which should create an array in a order which is determined by the questions asked. I'm trying very hard with js, but find it hard, with no experience. It doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work. Somehow the variables don't have a value. The things I've already done are probable way to stupid, I think they can be shortened a bit ;-). Hope someone will have a look at my code and help me out with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
 <head>
  <title>Keuze studievereniging</title>
  <style>
    fieldset {max-width:500px;}
    button {margin-top:30px;}
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
<h2>Sororities hulp</h2>

<p>Beantwoord onderstaande vragen om te zien welke vereniging het best bij je past.</p>

<form name="formulier"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Maak je keuze per vraag, vul alle onderdelen in.</legend>
  <div>
<p>Do you believe it is important that faith is emphasized in a sorority?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="vr1_1" name="VR1" value=1> Ja
  <input type="radio" id="vr1_0" name="VR1" value=0> Nee
<p>Would you participate in a hazing?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="vr2_1" name="VR2" value=1> Ja
  <input type="radio" id="vr2_0" name="VR2" value=0> Nee
<p>Would you like to fully integrate within the community of the sorority?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="vr3_1" name="VR3" value=1> Ja
  <input type="radio" id="vr3_0" name="VR3" value=0> Nee
<p>Do you like to party?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="vr4_1" name="VR4" value=1> Ja
  <input type="radio" id="vr4_0" name="VR4" value=0> Nee
<p>Would you sacrifice a free night of your own for the good of the sorority?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="vr5_1" name="VR5" value=1> Ja
  <input type="radio" id="vr5_0" name="VR5" value=0> Nee
<p>Would you like your sorority to be apart of a bigger european system?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="vr6_1" name="VR6" value=1> Ja
  <input type="radio" id="vr6_0" name="VR6" value=0> Nee
<p>Would you enjoy a weekly or by weekly bible study?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="vr7_1" name="VR7" value=1> Ja
  <input type="radio" id="vr7_0" name="VR7" value=0> Nee <br>
<button type="submit">Adviseer mij</button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
</form>

<p>De voor jou geschikste volgorde om te kijken is: </p>

<p id="uitslag"></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["formulier"]["VR1", "VR2", "VR3", "VR4", "VR5", "VR6", "VR7"].value;
  if (x == "") {
      alert("You have to answer each question for a good advice");
      return false;
  }
}

    var vvr11 = document.getElementsByName(vr1_1);
    console.log (vvr11);
    var vvr10 = document.getElementsByName(vr1_0);
    var vvr21 = document.getElementsByName(vr2_1);
    var vvr20 = document.getElementsByName(vr2_0);
    var vvr31 = document.getElementsByName(vr3_1);
    var vvr30 = document.getElementsByName(vr3_0);
    var vvr41 = document.getElementsByName(vr4_1);
    var vvr40 = document.getElementsByName(vr4_0);
    var vvr51 = document.getElementsByName(vr5_1);
    var vvr50 = document.getElementsByName(vr5_0);
    var vvr61 = document.getElementsByName(vr6_1);
    var vvr60 = document.getElementsByName(vr6_0);
    var vvr71 = document.getElementsByName(vr7_1);
    var vvr70 = document.getElementsByName(vr7_0);

    var alpha = vvr11 + vvr31 + vvr41;
    console.log (alpha);
    var rsk = vvr11 + vvr51 + vvr71;
    var vgste = vvr11 + vvr51 + vvr71;
    var nse = vvr11 + vvr51 + vvr71;
    var audentis = vvr21 + vvr41 + vvr51;
    var taste = vvr21 + vvr31 + vvr41;
    var aegee = vvr31 + vvr41 + vvr61;

    var sororities = [alpha, rsk, vgste, nse, audentis, taste, aegee];

    function sortering() {
        sororities.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
        document.getElementById("uitslag").innerHTML = sororities;
    }
    sortering ();
   </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You are getting errors in your console. Please read them and if you need help with them, use a search engine to find other questions about the same error. A great thing to use when learning JS in a browser is [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/988363).

Comment: Please tell me which errors you see in the console, I only see a couple of [object NodeList] at the end. As you can see on my code, I'm  really a beginner. I've worked for hours so far, don't mind that at all, but if someone can help me with pointing where I'm going wrong, I would really appreciate it. When it was easy to find for me, it had been fixed already.

Comment: Thank you for helping! Maybe it's better to point out what I want.
I want to create an advice for new students, which sorority does fits their interest the best. For that they have to answer 7 questions. All the answers are connected to 1 or more specific sororities. After they have filled in the form, it should show the result, the sorority with the most points at the top and so on. 

I see what you're doing on your fiddle, but don't understand how it should work for me. I've updated my fiddle now with the correct id's and names, that was a bit a mess. Hope you want to help me once more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a lot of potential to improve on your code, but I'll leave that part to you.

You are using

```
document.getElementsByName(vr1_1);
```

while you actually want to use

```
document.getElementsByName('VR1');
```

which gives you a NodeList of all elements with the name VR1, or use

```
document.getElementById('vr1_1').checked;
```

to explicitely get a particular element (here: vr1_1) to check its checked state.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at this mistake, that was a stupid one ;-). I've tried both solutions, but it doesn't help. Ive put it in a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/erwin_m/zL6oq5gj/

Comment: It does work, it just depends on what exactly you want to achieve and when. There you might want to do some additional work depending on that. Ie. getting a NodeList won't help you much, you might want the checked state, rather than the NodeList.Then you want to push it into an array, not concatenate it like strings ("a" + "b" results in "ab" not ["a", "b"]). Also, mind the Apostrophs, 'VR1' is a string, VR1 is an undefined variable leading to an empty NodeList.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle and put some comments in it that are hopefully useful, as I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve at what point. See: https://jsfiddle.net/4e8y9v6d/